# Persist Button activation/Deactivation state using React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I've been trying to maintain a buttons activation/deactivation state on page reload with respect to a user's subscription status (from push manager). The idea is when a user subscribes, the subscription button is deactivated and the buttons deactivated state is maintained on page reload.
But with what I've tried so far, Once the page loads, the `Toggle` state keeps switching between true and false endlessly..Here is the code I have.

```
   // True enables notification button, False disables the button
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);

    // Updates users subscription status
    const [subStatus, setSubStatus] = useState(false);


    useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch subscription status from local storage
        setSubStatus(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sub-status')));
         if(subStatus !== 'true'){
           setToggle(true);
         }else{
            setToggle(false);
         }

        //store subscription status to local storage
        localStorage.setItem('sub-status', JSON.stringify(subStatus));
    });
```

Function that handles Click

```
function handleUserSubscription(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(subReg => {
        subReg.pushManager.getSubscription().then(sub => {
        if(!sub){ 
            Notification.requestPermission(response => {
                if(response === 'granted'){
                    subscribeUser();
                }else if(response === 'blocked'){
                    setSubStatus(false);
                    setToggle(false);
                }
            });
        }
        })
    })
}

// Register/Subscribe User to Push
function subscribeUser(){
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(reg => {
        reg.pushManager.subscribe({ 
            userVisibleOnly: true,
            applicationServerKey: urlB64ToUint8Array(
            'BCsA21O2LqhM36sqjcxSf08qk0KE5sz9GWUA_kK2o_ZIpuTc_LTzCu8zVg_2tAVvT988PP2it7ZodjdAinMM6A8'
            )
        })
        .then( sub => {         
            console.log('user has been subscribed!', JSON.stringify(sub));
            //updateServerWithSubscription(getSub)
            setSubStatus(true);
            setToggle(false); //disable notification once user is subscribed
            
        })
        .catch( err => {
                alert('Unable to subscribe User', err);
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass in a dependency array then `useEffect` will run on every re-render which is causing the infinite loop. if you only want this logic called once on mount you should do something like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch subscription status from local storage
        const status = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sub-status'));
        
        setSubStatus(status);
        setToggle(Boolean(status !== 'true'));

        // (why do you need this?)
        // store subscription status to local storage
        // localStorage.setItem('sub-status', JSON.stringify(subStatus));
    }, []);
```

Comment: How does the localStorage get updated without  ```localStorage.setItem``` ?    I tried this, it still doesn't persist the button's toggle state

Comment: probably makes more sense to have that in `subscribeUser`.